# How to get specific value from key in Clojure Array?

Tags: arrays, clojure, clojurescript

I have data in clojure defined as:

```
(def data {:actor "damas.nugroho"
           :current-attributes [{:key "name", :value "adam"}
                                {:key "city", :value "jakarta"}]})
```

and I want to get the city value which means jakarta. How can I do that?

Comment: something like this: `(some #(when (= "city" (:key %)) (:value %)) (data :current-attributes))`

Comment: @leetwinski woahh.. you're genius.
It's worked. I've been strugling for this. 
How can I upvote your answer?
Thanks

Comment: If you want to get a value at a known path within a data structure like `data` you can use `get-in` e.g. `(get-in data [:current-attributes 1 :value])`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the data you have:

```
(def data
  {:actor "damas.nugroho"
   :current-attributes [{:key "name", :value "adam"}
                        {:key "city", :value "jakarta"}]})
```

And this is how you get at the city:

```
(->> (:current-attributes data)
     (some #(when (= (:key %) "city")
              (:value %))))
```

But the value of `:current-attributes` seems like a map, by essence. Assuming the keys don't repeat, consider transforming it into a map for easier manipulation.

```
(def my-new-data
  (update data :current-attributes
    #(into {} (map (juxt :key :value)) %)))
```

`my-new-data` will end up becoming this:

```
{:actor "damas.nugroho"
 :current-attributes {"name" "adam"
                      "city" "jakarta"}}
```

Getting the city is then just a nested map lookup, and can be done with `(get-in my-new-data [:current-attributes "city"])`
Also, `:current-attributes` is not specific and unless it may contain `:actor` as a key, or has a particular meaning you care about in some context, can be flattened.

Also, assuming the names of the keys in `current-attributes` are programmatic names, and follow the syntax of keywords in Clojure, you could convert them to keywords, and pour them all into a map:

```
(def my-newer-data
  (let [attrs (into data
                    (map (juxt (comp keyword :key) :value))
                    (:current-attributes data))]
    (dissoc attrs :current-attributes)))
```

Now we end up with this:

```
{:actor "damas.nugroho", :name "adam", :city "jakarta"}
```

And extracting city is just saying it, `(:city my-newer-data)`